# Kyber - Compression and Decompression Implementation Example

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, implementation, kyber

I have a question about the implementation of the functions

$$Compress_q(x,d) = \left\lfloor (2^d/q)\cdot x\right\rceil mod^{+}2^d$$

and

$$Decompress_q(x,d) = \left\lfloor (q/2^d)\cdot x\right\rceil$$

from Kyber.

I have copied two lines from the [GitRepo](https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/ref/polyvec.c), which contain the compression:

```
t[k]  = ((((uint32_t)t[k] << 11) + KYBER_Q/2)/KYBER_Q) & 0x7ff;
```

and the decompression

```
r->vec[i].coeffs[8*j+k] = ((uint32_t)(t[k] & 0x7FF)*KYBER_Q + 1024) >> 11;
```

for the case $d=11$.

- Regarding the first code snippet, why do we add $q/2$, what is the idea behind it? The shift is clear and with $0x7FF$ we can reduce this to values $mod^{+} 2^d$.
- In the second snippet why do we add $1024$? Wouldn't we have to shift first and then round down? So, how is the function $\left\lfloor ... \right\rceil$ represented?
- For me it seems that they have implemented it by using $\lfloor x \rceil = \lfloor x + 1/2\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line of code the addition of $q/2$ is to change the floor value $[2^dx/q]$ returned by the integer division into the rounded value $\lfloor 2^d/q\rceil$ value required for the function.

The constant `0x7ff` = $2^{11}-1=2^d-1$ is used to mask off the low 11-bits which is the same as reducing mod $2^d-1$.

In the second line of code the `0x7ff` seems to be a defensive measure to ensure that the `t[k]` has been reduced mod $2^d$. The addition of $2^{10}=2^d/2$ is again to convert the floor value returned by the left shift to the rounded value returned by the function.

Comment: Hi Daniel S, I agree with most of the things you said. The expression 0x7ff has the special character of working as $mod^{+} 2^d$. It seems as they have used $\lfloor x \rceil = \lfloor x + 1/2\rfloor$. The addition with $2^d/2$ is not so clear...

Comment: @TreeBook1 Note $[qx/2^d+1/2]=[(qx+2^d/2)/2^d]$`=(q*x+1024)>>11` for $d=11$.

Comment: Ok, I see it :) (Just write down what it says. :) ) And then similarily $\lfloor 2^d x / q\rceil = [(2^dx + q/2)/q] = ((x << 11) + q/2)/q$

Comment: Your left hand side should read something like $\lfloor 2^dx/q\rceil=[2^dx/q+1/2]=...$, but yes, I think that you have it.

Comment: Thanks! It think the crucial part is to note $\lfloor x \rceil = \lfloor x + 1/2\rfloor$. By the way is there a "clear" (mathematical) explanation of the rounding function $\lfloor x \rceil$ in the literature (I see this function often in a lattice crypto context... With definition: "rounding up to the nearest integer")? The border cases are interesting.

Comment: I don't know if wikipedia counts as literature (or clear), but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Rounding you may also be interested in the general methods of [uniform quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(signal_processing))